# Use h5bp / ant-build-script to remove debug output

Tags: ant, html5boilerplate

In the ant-build-script docs, it says I can mark my scripts with comments to state which Javascript files to minify & concat.

> <-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
>   <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
>  <cript
>   src="js/main.js"></script>
>  <-- end scripts -->

Is there a way I can use a similar approach to disable debug output, or remove specific lines in any files (Javascript, PHP, etc.)

An example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

> <!-- Remove these lines -->
>  console.log("Starting test");
>   console.log("Test 2");
>  <-- end remove these lines -->

Also, using that same example, if it could replace a line. An example of that is if I wanted it to change a variable from a local test directory to a remote production directory.

I hope that make sense and I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to remove lines of Javascript using the h5bp default Google Closure Compiler I suggest looking at @define JSDoc Tag

```
/** @define {boolean} */ 
var DEBUG = true;
```

Then, in your project.properties file look for: `# Closure Compiler Options` and set: `tool.closure.opts    = --define DEBUG=false`

Finally, wrap any code you want ignored, in production, in a conditional:

```
if (!DEBUG) {
    console.log("Starting test");
    console.log("Test 2");
}
```

The @define JSDoc Tag will help with your second question also.

```
/** 
 * @define {string} 
 */ 
var AJAX_URL = 'http://localhost/';

console.log(AJAX_URL);
```

with the compilations options: `--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS --define AJAX_URL=\'http://example.com/\'` (Note: you made need to fiddle with the quote escaping, depending on your platform) the resulting code is:

```
console.log("http://example.com/");
```

There are many ways to go about this of course, see:

- http://paulirish.com/2009/log-a-lightweight-wrapper-for-consolelog/
- http://dailyjs.com/2012/02/02/console/
- https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works for JavaScript, but I was hoping for a more generic "replace this with that", since I need to replace parts of XML files for Magento when I move a site to production.

Comment: There is nothing built into h5bp for this directly but you can look at the ant [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) task for examples of how to use filtersets. Look at the `-copyall` target in the `build.xml`. That is where h5bp does the bulk of copying files.